# Validate a localized date in a jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In jQuery's datepicker you can enter in an invalid date manually. I notice in Chrome's javascript debugger, the variable used to reference the datapicker shows "Invalid date". However, I cannot find any method in the datepicker that actually validates this nor do I have any idea how the javascript debugger is even capable of coming up with the text "Invalid date". I would prefer to avoid using some jQuery plugin to validate dates, as this seems overkill, especially considering that the javascript debugger can figure out that it's an invalid date, which means that I should be able to as well.

How can I determine if the date is valid? It must be independent of whatever localization is applied to the datepicker.

Comment: You can search for "javascript date validation" on SO. There should be plenty of answers.

Comment: There should be no need to validate the date. If javascript can already determine that its invalid, then that validation is already built into the datepicker control and reusing that is what I am looking for.

Comment: which datepicker plugin you are using? You have to see the documentation to find out 'Invalid date' msg.

Comment: `new Date("Foo bar blah baz")` produces "Invalid date" message. `new Date("2014-04-31")` produces a valid date object but it is invalid (April does not have 31 days). Can you specify what your input dates look like and which plugin you are using?

Comment: I'm using the DatePicker plugin. If you manually enter a date like 5555, you can see in the Chrome javascript debugger that it shows "Invalid Date". Clearly it knows how to determine that, so I should be able to as well.

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ or http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, sorry but simply stating jQuery DatePicker is too confusing.